# Exception from ExceptionTranslator does not return to flex

Tags: java, spring, apache-flex, spring-security, blazeds

I'm using Flex + Blazeds + Spring Security. Something weird is going on my ExceptionTranslator.

```
public class ProjectExceptionTranslator implements ExceptionTranslator {

   @Override
   public boolean handles(Class<?> arg0) {
        return true;
   }

   @Override
   public MessageException translate(Throwable throwable) {
        MessageException exception = new MessageException();

        if (throwable instanceof BadCredentialsException) {
            exception.setCode("08");
            exception.setMessage("Login error.");
        }

        if (throwable instanceof HibernateException) {
            exception.setCode("16");
            exception.setMessage("Data base error.");
        }

    return exception;
  }
```

}

All messages that spring throws, ex: BadCredentialsException, return to flex. But if my service throws something ex: HibernateException, it does not return to flex.

This is my config:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

<flex:message-broker>                       
    <flex:exception-translator ref="projectExceptionTranslator" />
    <flex:secured />
</flex:message-broker>
```

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Do you use Spring Framework for dependency injection? If it's true then your HibernateException may be wrapped into appropriate Spring exception.

Comment: @MaksymDemidas You're propably right, but I still can catch data base errors with the code above. All exceptions are handled by ProjectExceptionTranslator, my problem is when I return this exception. The exception does not get back to flex, It get lost somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by re-installing Flash Builder.